# how to make spring mvc convert the json array to arraylist(form submit with upload file)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was using below code to submit a form with fileupload to the backend spring mvc controller.

```
function submit() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileField = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");


    formData.append('mail', document.getElementsByName('mail')[0].value);
    formData.append('applicationName', 'myapp');

    // please remove the attachment if no file attached
    formData.append('attachment', fileField.files[0]);

    const releaseNotes = [{
        type: "java",
        overview: "good"
    },
    {
        type: "java2",
        overview: "good2"
    }]

    formData.append('releaseNotes', releaseNotes)

    fetch('springapi/addform', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)));

}
```

The controller looks like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody UserInfo save( UserInfo userInfo, HttpServletRequest request) throws RestException {

    myService.save(userInfo);

    return  userInfo;
}
```

The object looks like below.

```
public class UserInfo {
    private Long ID;
    private String mail;
    private String applicationName;
    private List<ReleaseNote> releaseNotes;

    }
```

When I ran this demo, it will report below exception.

```
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'releaseNotes'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.xxx.rest.jpa.entity.ReleaseNote] for property 'releaseNotes[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found] (.java:24) in http-bio-8080-exec-1
```

ps: If there is no need to use fileupload, I can solve this issue by using RestController and post the json to backend by below.

```
fetch(url,
  {method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    body: json    })
```

But since there is fileupload, so I have to use **FormData** instead of passing json to backend. How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post your `ReleaseNote` class?